# Visual Studio 2013 C# Designer won't let me move controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a project in Visual Studio 2013, and recently I have found that the controls on any form simply refuses to move when I use the mouse to drag and drop. Instead it lets me drag, then as soon as I move the cursor it snaps back into place. Then when I let go, it selects the control the cursor is hovering over.

The keyboard keys work fine, but I don't see why the program has simply changed the rules on me from a convenient system to an annoying and tedious one.

The controls are not locked and the problem effects every form. If it helps, I use Citrix as a thin client on my computer to access school programs.

Comment: Check the VS snapping settings. Could just be as you say - Visual Studio is 'snapping' the controls into place.

Comment: I hate to be 'that guy' but are you sure you're not debugging?

Comment: This started happening to me today also.  @DeeMac, it's not the same behavior as snapping in place, and changing the snapping settings has no effect.

Comment: I am running into this problem as well. I can't even change the names of items. And no I am not debugging.

Comment: While it sounds like there may be some subtle differences between our problems, I was able to resolve a similar issue with Visual Studio. Take a look at my answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925065](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925065).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Move Controls With Mouse on Windows Form Designer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925065/cant-move-controls-with-mouse-on-windows-form-designer)

Comment: Maybe duplicate but that question does not have an answer

Answer (score 1):

Hi can you please  check the CSS  styles

> setting:Tools--> Options-->HTML Designer-->CSS  styling-->  then check
>   the "Change position to absolute for controls added using toolbox,
>   paste or drag and drop"  check Box.

It  should   work