# Can't Move Controls With Mouse on Windows Form Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I recently installed Visual Studio 2013 Professional, and found that in the Windows Forms Application project type I'm unable to move any controls on a form in design mode. I tested a few alternatives out and found the following:

- Controls *can* be moved with the keyboard
- Controls *can* be resized by dragging the keypoints on the outline of the control
- Controls *can* be aligned using the commands in the Tools menu
- Controls *can* be moved by setting the `Location` field manually in the designer property grid
- Controls *can* be docked
- Controls *cannot* be moved with the mouse

Furthermore, as you can see in the image below, the "cross" icon that indicates that the controls are movable is not visible on any controls.

[image: A form showing no visible cross icon]

I've tried the following, but have not yet been able to correct the issue:

- Created a new project & solution (same issue)
- Created a new form (same issue)
- Verified that the `Locked` property of both the form and controls is set to `False`
- Verified that the form inherits from `Form` (as expected, as this is a standard installation and the first time I've used it)
- Googled for help (nothing that worked)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please contact Microsoft support via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: try reinstall the VS2013?

Comment: FYI: The cross only shows for __some__ more complicated container controls. It is __not__ supposed to show for a simple button. Try a restart of VS and then of your PC first..

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It took some time but I finally found a workaround, if not an answer. As it happens, periodically my computer will stop allowing me to drag-and-drop *anything*. The solution to this is to press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> (escape) key, which instantly restores functionality.

Comment: "this won't work... I can drag windows about. See now I hit Escape and... Ooh! it works!." 
Have a vote :)

Comment: I had to restart my computer.  Next time I will try this solution.

Comment: I had the same issue in the Workflow Designer and this solved that to. Thanks!

Comment: ESC has no effect for me.  Everything on the form is not movable with mouse.  I can use the arrows and the controls move.  I will try a restart of the computer since restarting VS 2015 Enterprise Update 1 has no effect either.

Comment: Finally it was a Windows 10 bug as we restarted the PC and it worked like a charm.  We found out when we were not able to move icon on the desktop as well.

Comment: @BrettWolfington I appreciate you sharing your solution, it resolved my issue. More importantly it was important that you marked your own response as an `Answer` - as it gets people attention more (as was the case with me).

Comment: I had the same issue with the dataset designer in VS 2013 and pressing `ESC` let me move tables again. Thanks a million!

Comment: Sorry, what the... it worked indeed, does anyone know what is the deal? I even restarted VS, the problem was still there, so maybe it is a Windows issue as someone mentioned above. Still, I am dying to figure out how pressing Esc solves it... I am stunned.

Answer (score 35):

I had this happening using multiple monitors.
Move VS to the main monitor (1) and all will work fine.
Greetz

Comment: This worked for me! Strange.. and makes me wonder why it happens

Comment: Also worked for me December 2020, VS 2019

Comment: Worked for me on VS 2019.  Also, the controls that I couldn't move were inside a tab control.  Controls outside the tab control (even on second monitor) were moveable.

Comment: I had this same problem in VS 2019 too. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: Worked for me as well. Strange that this strange bug is still there (April 2022, CS 2019).

Comment: This issue still has not been resolved in VS2022. So sad...

Comment: Worked for me on VS 2022.  Had been using the two monitors for months, but issue appeared suddenly and reboots do not address.  The monitor having the issue is secondary, and the Primary monitor which works ok is duplicated onto a Third (turned off) monitor.  Just decided to list my settings in case anyone else with the issue can verify settings we have in common.

Comment: OMG, awesome! You just saved my comp from flying out the window

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an older thread, but this problem still persists.  I am putting this here because I think some of these may work for others.  The top option works for me, but is by no means a permanent solution.  It helps to get your project completed though.  Design your forms on your main screen then move VS to your secondary monitor to code kinda thing.  I work off a laptop, so I don't like working on a small screen.

Some steps are rudimentary, but I was trying to be thorough.  Sometimes it's the simple solution.

Preliminary troubleshooting...

- Moving VS to main monitor(1) - this worked for me, but still doesn't allow me to use my 2 monitors
- Run installer, select Repair
- Run and cancel your project
- Press the Esc button and see if things return to normal
- Right click form "Lock Controls".  This should not have the blue outline, or right click on form/control>Lock Controls      and make sure nothing is locked.
- Rebuild project, close and open the form again.
- Snap to grid setting - Tools>Options>Windows Form Designer>General
- Restart VS with 100% scaling - drawing may be an issue.  I am not convinced it is not here since it works on the main screen      but not the 2nd or 3rd
- Dock property set to none for form/controls
- Moving items very slowly with mouse - another indication drawing may be an issue.
- Controls may not be docked in the container in which they reside.  Restart VS.  Try double clicking on the control, then move.       I think this is indicative of creating the control outside a container(say, on a form), dragging it into another      container(say, a tabControl) and then it not moving within that tabControl.  Additionally, try creating new controls within their intended container and then trying to move them.
- Close VS, delete C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxxxxxxxx folder
- Mouse driver - some software may cause issues here.
- Absolute positioning - Tools>Options>Web Form Designer>CSS Styling>Change position...
- Right click any item under toolbox and select "reset toolbox"

Requires Reboot...

- Close VS.  Delete some config files with current dates (devenv.exe.config, toolbox.tbd, toolbox_reset.tbd, toolboxindex.tbd, toolboxindex_reset.tbd) and reboot the PC.  These are found in a directory like C:\Users\tdevy97\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_18c2eb4a where the last folder(15.0_18c2eb4a) is some random name.  Reboot.  Restart VS.
- Corrupt toolbox? Close Visual Studio, Open the “c:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0” folder and remove all the .TBD files, Start regedit, Find the “HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ToolboxControlsInstaller_AssemblyFoldersExCache” and “HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ToolboxControlsInstallerCache” keys, Remove everything from these keys leaving them empty, before you removing it, (back up your registry first), Reboot, Run Visual Studio again and wait until it recreates all items in the toolbox.

Last resorts...

- Open command prompt as admin, navigate to your "IDE" directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE) and run the following commands...

  - devenv.exe /resetskippkgs, it will clear all SkipLoading tags that have been added to VSPackages by users who want to avoid       loading problem VSPackages.
  - devenv.exe /resetsettings, it will restore Visual Studio default settings. Optionally resets the settings to the specified       .vssettings file.
  - devenv.exe /resetuserdata, it will take a couple of minutes to run as Visual Studio cleans up and sets itself back to its           original state. You may open Task Manager at this point to check whether the devenv.exe process is still running. After         it has completed running, you can restart Visual Studio.
- devenv.exe /uninstall /force - complete uninstall.  Reboot.  Reinstall.  Rock on!

Comment: Hitting <ESC> worked for me. I can't believe it... Thank you, anyway!

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I had to change the **Dock** property to **None**.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue and tried solving it using some of the aforementioned methods, including pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, rebooting, and deleting the folder in AppData, but none of these worked for me.

**"Solution"**
I have a dual screen setup, and what I eventually did notice is that if Visual Studio starts up on *Screen 1* and is then moved to *Screen 2*, the components will snap back to their initial location after being clicked and dragged.  After moving the Visual Studio window back to *Screen 1*, the components click and drag as usual.  I am unsure of the cause of this since it never used to be a problem, but for anyone using dual/multiple screens, this may "solve" the issue.

Comment: After trying other options with no luck, This worked for me on a dual screen. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I just found myself in similar, but slightly different situation - I could drag all controls without the "cross" icon such as buttons, but could not drag any control that had the "cross" icon such as group boxes and panels. One workaround that worked was to use the "arrow" keys to move the controls, but only a computer reboot fixed the issue. The solution, posted by Brett Wolfington did not work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution!!

I had the same problem:
Holding the mouse button and trying to move the element with no effects!

My solution:
Try after pressing the mouse button to move the element very slowely - it works!
I think it has maybe something to do with the mouse speed/acceleration settings. I changed them to the maximum. I guess VS has a problem with that. When i move the mouse slowely at the beginning then it works just fine!

Comment: yes it is the case, move the mouse very slowly, when the control gets dragged then you can drag faster. In this case alignment suggestions don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to a slightly different question, but my googling lead me here, so perhaps it helps someone else.

If no movement works, also not with keyboard, check the "locked" property. That was it for me in a colleagues project, so I was not aware he had locked it.

The controls also have a tiny lock icon so if you look closely you will notice.

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me. These are the steps that worked for me:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete the Visual Studio AppData folder, usually at *C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio*. My folder was named *15.0_b148b13d*, but your folder may have a similar name.

After deleting, Visual Studio took some time to initialize but I could finally drag the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Seems its a drawing error. The controls actually moves, but there is a short time delay before you see it!

Comment: While I can't speak for everyone experiencing this problem, in my situation the error was *not* a drawing error or delay.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was that a big 7-Zip file was dragged and dropped to an archive just before, a huge file. While this drag & drop was in progress Windows can't do another one. It's a global singleton operation. In .NET the call 'DragDrop.DoDragDrop()' throws an exception 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' with a message "A drag operation is already in progress" (or similar). A good programming style would have reported this exception to the user but Visual Studio simply ends the drag attempt without info. So, the solution in my case was to let the Drop finish or abort the whole operation.