# Can't move anything or do anything in my form

Tags: vb.net

I can't move anything in my `Form1` form, nor do anything on the form. Other forms work as expected. The form is not locked.

I use MetroFramework theme and elements.

Furthermore all my controls, that are in the form, show at the bottom:

[image: GIF / Picture demonstrating my issue]

Comment: Have you checked this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925065/cant-move-controls-with-mouse-on-windows-form-designer)?