# visual studio winforms cannot move with move icon

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have re-installed visual studio and the problem seems to be continued, I removed every visual studio related files including AppData(I am not meaning by entire AppData folder, AppData > Local > Microsoft > VisualStudio) and entirely removed folders with containing string "vs", "visual studio" in folder name except for visual studio code files in C drive, D drive, E drive. I even checked registries. I have one monitor.

This is not a really critical issue but its pretty annoying when I cannot use the move icon to move objects. Buttons can be moved but move icon doesn't seem to work at all for me.

Here's video how it looks like: https://youtu.be/NJlAwXp9aWw

As you can see my mouse gets snapped out of that button every time I click, and I cannot move with these buttons. I can use arrow keys to move, but if I do that I won't be able to use auto distance snap system at all. If I want that snap system then I'll have write down the size and resize it, and then re-write size in properties tab. This is too much work for me to just to move 1 object. I have to create and move at least 100 objects and I don't want to do this every time.

And I have read this question before: [Can't Move Controls With Mouse on Windows Form Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925065/cant-move-controls-with-mouse-on-windows-form-designer), and none of them helped me. I STILL can't drag anything except ones for not using move icons.

Comment: It seems to be an issue can't be reproduced, maybe you can try to report a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8).

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing `esc` in your keyboard or check if the locked property of the control is set to false.

Comment: I tried it while ago, and it didn't work. My locked property is not false. If it is locked then I would be able to see a locked icon..