# Visual Studio WinForms Designer: Unable to Move Controls inside of TabPage

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, .net-core, tabcontrol, tabpage

I am using a .net core 3.1 WinForms Application.

Moving controls works perfectly fine outside of a tab control, but the moment I place a control inside of a TabPage I am unable to move it again. I can no longer select it from the designer either, and the only way I can is to select it from the properties menu.

After I access it from there, the only thing I can do is resize it, as shown in the image below:

[image]

Things I tried:

- Made sure the component was not locked.
- Pressed escape (as per the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925065/cant-move-controls-with-mouse-on-windows-form-designer))
- Rebuilt the solution.
- Restarted Visual Studio.
- Deleted Visual Studio's AppData folder.
- Made sure my Dock property was set to none.
- Ensured Visual Studio is on my primary monitor

I really want to use tab pages with my application, but I don't want to keep resizing it everytime I want to move something, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have any third-party controls in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I decided to switch my project from .Net Core to .Net Framework and it now works, so it must have something to do with .Net Core. I'll leave this open if anyone has a solution for .Net Core.

Comment: There's no solution for .Net Core. It's a [work in progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs-roadmap) (see the .Net section). Some controls still don't work as expected (or at all). It will be fully functional when One.Net is complete. For now, create a Net.Core WinForms Projects to prepare for Core 5 and to report problems/bugs/glitches, to help fixing the platform, which is quite important.

Comment: Confirming, i just switched a project from Framework to core, and this is the 1st mishap i bumped into, sometimes a button is getting moved, but most of the time not.